# Type error Can't find solution

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. I can't find where there is a mistake.

```
stop();

var city:String;
var par_id:String;
var key:String;
var units:String;

var data_xml_url:String = "data.xml";
var user_data:XML = new XML();
var data_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(data_xml_url);
var dataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(data_url);

dataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataLoaded);

function dataLoaded(e:Event):void
{
user_data = XML(dataLoader.data);
city = user_data.city.toString();
par_id  = user_data.parid.toString();
key  = user_data.key.toString();
units  = user_data.units.toString();

}

icons_mc.visible = false;

var weather_xml_url:String = "http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/"+city+"?     cc=*&link=xoap&par="+par_id+"&key="+key+"&unit="+units;

var weather:XML = new XML();
var weather_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(weather_xml_url);
var weatherLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(weather_url);

weatherLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, weatherLoaded);

function weatherLoaded(e:Event):void
{
weather = XML(weatherLoader.data);
temp_txt.text = weather.cc.tmp;

icons_mc.visible = true;

var weather_icon:int = Number(weather.cc.icon.toString())+1;
icons_mc.gotoAndStop(weather_icon);

}
```

Maybe this is wrong: `user_data = XML(dataLoader.data);`?

Comment: Did you mean to have a tab between the `?` and `cc` in your URL?

Comment: This probably means that you XML is malformed, not your code. Show us your XML.

Answer (score 0):

First would good to know where you are getting the error, what line, because you are loading you different XML, data and weather but usually that error means a problem on the original XML structure being loaded. Try to trace dataLoader.data and weatherLoader.data before assign them to the XML variable and look for problems on the XML string, most likely you will need to add a root level

Answer (score -1):

*user_data = XML(dataLoader.data)* is wrong.
Use this:

```
user_data = XML(e.target.data);
```

Comment: Ops, I accidentally deleted my comment... so again: Why is it wrong exactly, in your opinion? What would this trace you: trace(weatherLoader == e.target);? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#data